# Linear interpolation of missing data from table of values

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, interpolation, subroutine

Here is an excerpt from a data file, my starting point:

```
Marker      Distance_1  Distance_2  ID
.
.
.
30          13387412    34.80391242 seq-SN_FIRST
31          13387444    34.80391444 seq-SN_Second
31.1             
31.2             
32          13387555    39.80391    seq-SN_Third
.
.
.
```

This is a tab-delimited file of multiple rows of four elements each. First row is a header. After that, numerous rows of data. The vertical dots are not actually in the real file, but they are here just to represent that data similar to the actual rows shown occur before and after the example fo rows explicitly shown.

Some of the data rows are "full", that is, all four cell entries contain something. Other rows are "blank", with only a first actual entry but followed by 3 tab delimited single spaces. Those white spaces in the blank rows need to be "filled in." The filling in will be done by linear interpolation, using the corresponding cell entries of the immediately preceding and immediately succeeding rows. For example, missing `Distance_1 values`, in column 2, will be interpolated using the value `13387444` of the preceding row and the value `13387555` of the succeeding row. Similarly so for the column 3 values. Column 4 values are just ignored here.

The first goal of the script is to identify the blocks of data that require filling and their flanking "full" lines. Blank lines will contain 3 tabbed single spaces and will be ID'd that way. Once found, the consecutive sets of blank lines plus flanking full lines are sent to subroutine for interpolation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

die "usage: [ map positions file post SAS ]\n\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

my @file = ();

while (my $line = <$ARGV[0]>) {
  chomp $line;
  push(@file, $line);
}

my @consecutive_lines = (); # array collects a current set of consecutive lines requiring linear interpolation
my @filled = ();    # my final array, hopefully correctly filled in

#####
# search for consecutive set of lines in @file
#####

for (my $i = 0; $i < $#file; $i++) {          #  $#file returns the index of the last element in @file

  if ($file[$i] !~ /(?:\t\s){3}/) {           # if not a blank line
                                              # but a "full line"
    push(@filled, $file[$i]);                 # push the header and full lines, until...
  }

  elsif ($file[$i] =~ /(?:\t\s){3}/) {        # ...a blank line is found

    push (@consecutive_lines, $file[$i - 1]); # push preceding full line into array

    while ($file[$i] =~ /(?:\t\s){3}/ and $i < $#file) {  # keep pushing lines, so long as they are blank
                                                          # or end of file
      push(@consecutive_lines, $file[$i++]);
    }

    push(@consecutive_lines, $file[$i]) ;     # else we reach next full line, so push it into array

    my @fillme = linearInterpolation(@consecutive_lines); # send set of lines out for filling

    push(@filled, @fillme);                   # push filled in set of lines into the final array

    @consecutive_lines = ();                  # reset or undef array @consecutive_lines for next cycle

  }    # end of elsif

}    # end of for loop
```

Thanks to user @Kenosis for lots help with the above, which I have since modified (hopefully not mangled).

Next is the linear interpolation. It is here where I am trying to link the first phase of the script to the second phase. And it is not working well so far.

My goal is to hand off the array `@incoming` to the subroutine. This array is then split up, so that the actual cell entries are "visible" and can be indexed by the array, and so called upon. I have been trying to figure out how to do this for the column 2 values for `Distance_1` first. I feel like this script gets close and it begins to stray at the point just after the interpolated values are calculated.

```
#####
# subroutine linear interpolation
#####

sub linearInterpolation {
  my @incoming = @_;    # array of consecutive set of lines

  my @splitup;                  # declare new array, will be a "split up" version of @incoming
  my ($A, $B, $C, $D, $E);      # variables for linear interpolation
  my @fillme;                   # declaring the "emtpy" array to be filled in
  my @dist_1_fills;             # array of interpolated values for dist_1

  for (my $i = 0;
    $i < scalar @incoming; $i++)     # loop to split up lines of @incoming
  {                                  # into indexed cell entries
    chomp $incoming[$i];             # and make new array of them
    my @entries = split('\t', $incoming[$i]);
    push(@splitup, @entries);
  }

  $A = $splitup[1];                   # cell entry in column 2 of preceding full line
  $B = $splitup[-3];                  # cell entry in column 2 of succeeding full line

  $C = $splitup[2];                   # cell entry in column 3 of preceding full line
  $D = $splitup[-2];                  # cell entry in column 3 of succeeding full line
  $E = scalar @incoming - 1;          # equals number of lines in the set minus 1

  for (my $i = 1; $i < $E; $i++) {    # need to start finding appropriate
                                      # number interpolated values, given number of
    my @dist_1_fills =
        interpvalues($A, $B, $E, $i); # of lines in consecutive set of lines

    for ($i = 0; $i < scalar @splitup; $i += 4) {
      push(@fillme, $splitup[$i], $dist_1_fills[$i], "dist_2_fills", "--");
                                      # fourth column values will be ignored or filled with --.
                                      # "dist_2_fills" just occupying it's proper spot until I can figure out distance 1 fills
    }
  }
}

#########

sub interpvalues {                  # subroutine to find interpolated values
  my ($A, $B, $E, $i) = @_;
  my $dist_1_answers = (($B - $A) / ($E)) * $i + $A;
  return $dist_1_answers;
}
```

The code gets confused in the second part that deals with finding the interpolated values and sending them back to the first part of the code to finally fill in the data set. I think specifically my biggest (though probably not my only) problem is trying to fill in the blank lines with the proper values after they have been calculated in the second subroutine.

Any hints and clues are greatly appreciated!

Comment: your code was all fairly clear until the last for-loop, have you missed some? what is interpvalues, $bps,$cMs? which aspect of your code is not working?

Comment: Yes, I just added the final parts, such as they are.

Comment: This: `$file[ $i ] !~ /(?:\t\s){3}/ )  # if not a blank line` actually checks for blank lines.  Change it to: `$file[ $i ] =~ /(?:\t\s){3}/ )`.

Comment: hi @Kenosis...recognize your handy work!  I changed that line so I could add in an extra conditional statement that would "catch" full lines, such as header and others, in order to begin filling my final array of data. Elsewhere, the script is supposed to push in interpolated data, when appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program will do what you need. It expects the inout file name as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @saved;
my @needed;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;

  # Pass hrough headers and junk
  unless ($fields[0] and $fields[0] =~ /\d/) {
    print "$_\n";
    next;
  }

  # Save x-value for records without a y-value
  if ($fields[1] !~ /\d/) {
    push @needed, $fields[0];
    next;
  }

  # We have a filled-out row. Calculate any intermediate missing ones
  if (@needed) {
    if ($saved[0] == $fields[0]) {
      die sprintf qq(Duplicate marker values %.1f at line %d of "%s"\n), $saved[0], $., $ARGV;
    }
    my ($a1, $b1) = solve_linear(@saved[0,1], @fields[0,1]);
    my ($a2, $b2) = solve_linear(@saved[0,2], @fields[0,2]);
    while (@needed) {
      my $x = shift @needed;
      my $y1 = $a1 * $x + $b1;
      my $y2 = $a2 * $x + $b2;
      print join("\t", $x, $y1, $y2), "\n";
    }
  }

  print "$_\n";
  @saved = @fields;
}

sub solve_linear {
  my ($x0, $y0, $x1, $y1) = @_;
  my ($dx, $dy) = ($x1 - $x0, $y1 - $y0);
  my $aa = $dy / $dx;
  my $bb = ($y0 * $dx - $x0 * $dy)  / $dx;
  return ($aa, $bb);
}
```

**output**

```
Marker  Distance_1  Distance_2  ID
.
.
.
30  13387412  34.80391242 seq-SN_FIRST
31  13387444  34.80391444 seq-SN_Second
31.1  13387455.1  35.303913996  --
31.2  13387466.2  35.803913552  --
32  13387555  39.80391  seq-SN_Third
.
.
.
Tool completed successfully
```

Comment: i'm getting a division by 0 error in line 42...  I find this code very elegant.  For column 4, I just need to insert or push in a blank, or a --, or NA, or something. There is no interpolation for column 4.

Comment: I have added a test to my solution that will die if this happens, with a warning saying where in the file the duplicate was found. You need to decide what you want to do in this cicumstance. I have also changed it to use `--` for column four of calculated lines.

Comment: thanks, let me study this script.  this looks really great. the interpolated values are close but a little different from what i was expecting, though.

Comment: I am pretty sure my values are correct. The code calculates `a` and `b` for a linear function `f(x) = ax + b` that passes through the point preceding and the point following the list of empty record. Here, `x` is `Marker`, `f1(x)` is `Distance_1` and `f2(x)` is `Distance_3`. Let me know if there's any part of the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: If I understand the coding correctly, the linear interpolation as implemented in the sub routine utilizes the values of the first field. Is that correct?  If so, then I would need to change the routine slightly by finding a new parameter: the number of lines in the particular empty record being dealt with in this pass of the cycle. So in effect, the difference between field value in preceding full line and field value in succeeding full line is divided by 1 - new parameter.

Comment: This just averages the amount of interpolation needed per line. Then that average amount is added to the field values in succession. I think in other words, `x` should not be `Marker` but should be a difference between the `Distance_1` value in preceding full line and `Distance_1` again but in the succeeding full line. Or rather the abs value of that (or reverse the subtraction order). If I am understanding the script correctly.

Comment: I am also not following the `@saved` array's role. I don't see where values are pushed into it before going off to the subroutine. I need to study this syntax and how it affects arrays. Also, where in the script is the "--" symbol added in for column 4 fields?

Comment: I follow the role of `@saved` now. This script is very sleek! Are you an engineer?

Comment: As it stands, the new values of `Distance_1` and `Distance_2` are proportional to the values of `Marker`. Do you want the interval between successive `Distance` values to be the same for all newly-calculated records in a block, independent of the values of `Marker`? I am an electronics engineer and computer software consultant. I've been doing this for 35 years now, so if I couldn't code well by now I should give up!

Comment: @eric: What the code does is use the values of `(Marker, Distance)` from before and after the record before the sequence of blank records as `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)`. The `solve_linear` subroutine calculates values for `a` and `b` whereby the linear function `Distance = a * Marker + b` passes through both pairs of values. Then the new values are calculated by applying the function to the intermediate values of `Marker`.

Comment: @eric: `@saved` keeps a copy of the values in `@fields` for the previous non-blank record. The `Marker` values for any blank record are stored in `@needed`. So when the end of a sequence of blanks is reached, the record preceding the sequence is in `@saved`, the record following is in `@fields`, and the values of `Marker` for the records that need to be inserted are in `@needed`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to this, so that the linear interpolation is based not on the values in the first column but rather on the values in the second and third columns. Thanks especially to users @Kenosis and @Borodin. I have accepted Kenosis' answer to a previous question, and I have accepted Borodin's here, even though I post this revision in the "answer your own question" section. Is posting a revision here acceptable? I skimmed the FAQ about this but haven't found anything relevant yet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my @saved;
my @needed;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;

    # Does the current line actually exist AND does it contain one or more digits.
    unless ($fields[0] and $fields[0] =~ /\d/) {
    # If no, this is the header, so print it. If yes, advance.
    print "$_\n";
    #after printing header, go back to <> and read in next line.
    next;
  }

  # Is the second cell of the current line devoid of digits?
  if ($fields[1] !~ /\d/) {                
  # If no, advance. If yes, remember $field[0], the Marker.
  push @needed, $fields[0];              
  # After pushing, go back to <> and read in next line.
  next;
 }

  # If we are here, we must have a filled-out row.
  # Does @needed have any values? If no, advance. If yes,
  if (@needed) {
    if ($saved[0] == $fields[0]) {
      die sprintf qq(Duplicate marker values %.1f at line %d of "%s"\n), $saved[0], $., $ARGV;
     }
    # Else send preceding dist_1 value, succeeding dist_1 value,
    # preceding dist_2 value, succeeding dist_2 value, 
    # and number of emtpy lines to subroutine.
    my ($dist_1_interval, $dist_2_interval) = interval_sizes($saved[1], $fields[1], $saved[2],   $fields[2], scalar @needed);     
    # Current size of @needed is saved as $size and is used to help with iteration.
# So long as @needed contains values...
my $size = scalar @needed;
while (@needed) {
  # ...remove left-most Marker value from array @needed.
  my $x = shift @needed;
  # Interpolated values for dist_1 and dist_2 are
  # (respective interval size x iteration of while loop) + preceding values.
  my $new_dist_1 = ($dist_1_interval * (1 + ($size - (scalar @needed + 1)))) + $saved[1];
  my $new_dist_2 = ($dist_2_interval * (1 + ($size - (scalar @needed + 1)))) + $saved[2];
  print join("\t", $x, $new_dist_1, $new_dist_2, "--"), "\n";
  }
}     
      # We are here since current line is already a filled-in row.
      print "$_\n";
      # Print this row and assign it to @saved. Return to <>.
      @saved = @fields;
} 

sub interval_sizes {
  # $A = preceding dist_1, $B = succeeding dist_1, 
  # $C = preceding dist_2, $D = succeeding dist_2,
  # $E = number of needed distances.
  my ($A, $B, $C, $D, $E) = @_; 
  # I need an interval size for dist_1 based on difference between $B and $A.
  my $dist_1_interval = ($B - $A)/($E + 1);
  # I need an interval size for dist_2 based on difference between $D and $C.
  my $dist_2_interval = ($D - $C)/($E + 1);
  return ($dist_1_interval, $dist_2_interval);
 }
```